# Position displays in retina+non-retina multiple display setup in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, display, multiple-monitors, resolution

I am using Macbook Pro with Retina display (2880x1800, scale set to 200%), and I also have my second monitor (1440x900, scale set to 100%) connected. Both screens are physically almost the same size.

In the "Select and rearrange displays" menu in Windows 10 display settings, 200% scale of the retina display does not affect the size of the "rectangle" that represents the display, and my retina display is twice as big as my non-retina display.

This is not very comfortable to use, when I move the mouse pointer to the second display it's always "stuck" and I have to move it to the bottom or to the top based on how displays are positioned in this menu.

Is there any way to make the rectangles "the same size" in this menu, and let my mouse always move to the second monitor?

I tried setting my second display resolution to 2880x1800 and then scale it to 200%, but it doesn't support resolution that high. Is there any other way to achieve that?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem with my 2017 iMac. I have a second display that is not retina resolution connected to it, so moving the cursor between them is a huge pain.

Have you found a solution to this problem?